# Unexpected version of dependency installed

Tags: firebase, npm, angularfire2

My package.json file includes these lines:

```
"angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.1"
"firebase": "^4.1.3"
```

When I try to install this, I get a warning:

> npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc0 requires a peer of firebase@^3.6.6 but none was installed.

So I tried changing the second line to `"firebase": "^3.6.6"` but then I get:

> npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of firebase@^4.0.0 but none was installed.

Now, I know I can fix this by removing the `^` from the first line, but I don't understand the behavior as it's currently written.
Why is it not only sometimes going back a version when it should only go forward, but also always picking the wrong one for the Firebase version?

Comment: are you working with ionic

Comment: @EmekaObianom Nope.

Answer (score 1):

Try `npm install firebase@4.0.0 --save`

Comment: Please give more explanations on how this solves the issue

Comment: That solves the immediate problem, but it doesn't explain why the caret notation isn't working as expected.